# Enable ajax in asp.net web application in vs 2012

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

The question might be trivial, but I am looking for some best options.

I have build a page that have a grid and an other editor kind of panel which have some drop downs , textboxes etc.,

When I select I row in a grid, the details will populate on the controls exists in the panel.
also in panel based on the value of dropdown, the controls may be hidden or visible.

I want to do all these operations without asp.net post backs. 
May be by using ajax, can somebody give me start up how to achieve this in asp.net 4.5.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ASP.NET UpdatePanel controls enable you to build rich, client-centric Web applications. By using UpdatePanel controls, you can refresh selected parts of the page instead of refreshing the whole page with a postback. This is referred to as performing a partial-page update.

Refer Posts

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001(v=vs.100).aspx
http://www.asp.net/web-forms/tutorials/aspnet-ajax/understanding-asp-net-ajax-updatepanel-triggers

Sample application

http://www.aspdotnet-suresh.com/2012/05/ajax-updapanel-control-with-triggers.html

Answer (score 1):

Probably for a starting point and the easiest solution, you should take a look at the [`<asp:UpdatePanel />`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb399001%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

The will easily allow you to wrap your existing Markup with this Ajax control and create the desired effect. A **downside** to the update panel is that if you then try to mix it with other JavaScript/jQuery code, then it can get messy.

Another option would be to learn how to use [jQuery Ajax](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) and how to post form inputs to your server and then handle the response back from the server.